# get server side event for image click inside a Telerik:RadGrid control

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am new to Rad controls..

I have an image inside a column of RadGrid..when this image is clicked, I want to update another AjaxPanel..but I am not able to find the event where I can do this..

I tried like this..

```
...
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgEdit" runat="server" 
                             ImageUrl="Images/edit.png" 
                             OnClick="EditImage_Click" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
...
....
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ImgEdit">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadAjaxPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
....
```

and

```
    protected void EditImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I also tried below code in Page_Load..

```
((ImageButton)(RadGrid1.FindControl("ImgEdit"))).Click += 
                               new ImageClickEventHandler(EditImage_Click);
```

but nothing seems to be working..

Please HELP...

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `EditImage_Click` event of a imagebutton you can gave a command name to this imagebuttom and call `grid row command event` and use this row command event instead of `EditImage_Click` event

Comment: `row command event` not available in RadGrid is the problem..don't know what is the alternate event

Comment: Refer this URL : http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grdcommanditemtemplate.html

Answer (score 1):

you missed CommandName property, ItemCommand will occur only if "Buttons within a GridView control can also invoke some of the built-in functionality of the control. To perform one of these operations, set the CommandName property of a button"

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TempCol" >  
                         <ItemTemplate>  
                             <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandName="DoEdit" />  
                         </ItemTemplate>  
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Event handler

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e) 
        { 
            if (e.CommandName == "DoEdit") 
            { 
                //dosomething

            } 

        }
```